# Spring request parameters saved by binder

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, concurrency

I think i may have discovered a critical bug with springs web binder, or more likely, I am doing something horribly wrong. Basically, data from one servlet request is somehow copied to another request.

Spring version 4.1.5

I have a simple model object with 1 parameter.

```
public class MyModelAttribute {

private String myModelParameter;

public String getModelParameter() {
return myModelParameter;
}

public void setModelParameter(String myModelParameter) {
    this.myModelParameter = myModelParameter;
}

}
```

I intialize a binder for my object like so in my controller

```
@InitBinder("myModelAttribute")
protected void initMyModelBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
binder.setValidator(myValidator);
binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(false));
}
```

then there is a controller method like this

```
public ModelAndView someRequestMapping(@Valid @ModelAttribute("myModelAttribute") MyModelAttribute myModelAttribute,
    BindingResult bindingResult) {

...
}
```

I created a test that spams this controller with requests and sometimes I see something horrifying. The parameter on my model is not what was submitted, but rather, a different value that was submitted in an earlier request. It could make one user get another user's data. Basically, it seems like the target object on the data binder is saved from earlier. If I get the parameter directly from the request it will be the expected parameter.

Comment: Add your test, also what is your validator doing?

Comment: The validator wasnt the problem, it was the string trimmer editor. I mistakenly assumed the StringTrimmerEditor was thread safe.

Comment: Next time post the actual code instead of modified code that way we can really help you!.

Comment: Lying to the doctor is never good.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the StringTrimmer editor... it wasnt actually set up as I posted in the code. The binder intialization was like this. And it turns out the StringTrimmerEditor is not stateless. So the answer is to initialize the binder as it is in the question. Not like how it is below.

```
@InitBinder("myModelAttribute")
protected void initMyModelBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
binder.setValidator(myValidator);
binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, STRING_TRIMMER);
}
```

The issue is better described here https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12547